# Running multiple RabbitMQ queues sequentially

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

We are using Spring Boot AMQP to handle messages. We have multiple queues and some of them depend on other queues. I want to make sure that queues wait for others to complete their job. For example:

Let's say I have 2 queues (A and B) and there are 20 messages each waiting to be processed. I want B to wait for A to complete processing of 20 messages before starting to work.

Is there a built-in way to accomplish this?

We tried AMQP's priority but did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `autoStartup` to `false` on the `@RabbitListener`. (You can stop/start containers via its `id` using the `RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry` bean). If you are not using the annotation and creating your container beans yourself then just use the container bean to manage its lifecycle.

Then, enable event publishing for `ListenerContainerIdleEvent`s; then you can detect when a container goes idle, stop it, then start the next one.

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#idle-containers